# Hittest in AS3 between an irregular object & a rectangle and get the top y coordinate of the overlapping area

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, hittest

How can I test for a collision between a rectangle and an irregular object in AS3? And how can I then get the lowest y value of the overlap (the top)?

**Edit**
Thanks a lot for the answer, but the `checkCollision` method always returns false. This is my code:

```
public static function checkCollision(object1:*, object2:*):Boolean{
    var object1Rect:Rectangle = object1.getRect(stage);
    var object2Rect:Rectangle = object2.getRect(stage);

    var bitmapData1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
        object1.width, 
        object1.height, 
        true, 
        0
    );
    var bitmapData2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
        object2.width, 
        object2.height, 
        true, 
        0
    );

    bitmapData1.draw(object1);
    bitmapData2.draw(object2);

    var bCollide:Boolean = bitmapData1.hitTest(
        new Point(object1Rect.x, object1Rect.y),
        255,
        bitmapData2,
        new Point(object2Rect.x, object2Rect.y),
        255
    );

    bitmapData1.dispose();
    bitmapData2.dispose();

    return bCollide;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a complex shape, use bitmapdata like the below. This will work for all shapes.

Should you then still need to know the lowest Y value, don't forget it could be on the X as well. There's an additional function in there (getHitPoint) to calculate that, which only needs to be run on a successful hit test. It can be optimised through passing the bitmap data from the original function into it, but I kept it separate to help it remain readable.

```
package kazo 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author KM
     */
    public class TestCases extends Sprite
    {

        private var rect    :Sprite;
        private var circle  :Sprite;

        public function TestCases() { }

        /**
         * Start the test case
         */
        public function start():void {
            trace('Starting test case');

            // Rectangle
            rect = new Sprite();
            // Circle
            circle = new Sprite();

            // Draw the rectangle. Center point must be TOP LEFT
            // If you're using Flash Professional, place everything at 0,0 inside the MC
            rect.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
            rect.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            rect.graphics.endFill();

            // Draw the circle. Center point is TOP LEFT, so the X and Y of the circle need to be equal to the radius
            circle.graphics.beginFill(0xffff00);
            circle.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 50);
            circle.graphics.endFill();

            // Add them
            addChild(rect);
            addChild(circle);

            // Position
            rect.x = 0;
            rect.y = 100;

            // Position
            circle.y = 400;
            circle.x = 0;

            // Frame loop
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameFunc);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function frameFunc(e:Event):void {
            // move them around
            rect.y += 1;
            circle.y -= 1;
            circle.x += 1;
            rect.x += 1;

            // Check for collisions. If found, stop. Pass 'true' as the final param if you want it to draw to the screen
            if (checkCollision(rect, circle)) {
                trace(getHitPoint(rect, circle));

                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameFunc);
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   _obj1
         * @param   _obj2
         * @param   _debug
         * @return
         */
        private function checkCollision(_obj1:Sprite, _obj2:Sprite, _debug:Boolean = false):Boolean {
            // Draw the first item to bitmapdata
            var bmd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_obj1.width, _obj1.height, true, 0);
            // ..and the second
            var bmd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_obj2.width, _obj2.height, true, 0);

            // Now draw them
            bmd1.draw(_obj1);
            bmd2.draw(_obj2);

            // If we're in debug, also add the bitmap to the stage so we can see where we are
            if (_debug) {
                var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd1);
                bmp.x = _obj1.x;
                bmp.y = _obj1.y;
                addChild(bmp);

                var bmp2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd2);
                bmp2.x = _obj2.x;
                bmp2.y = _obj2.y;
                addChild(bmp2);
            }

            // Hit test including alpha channel. Obj1 X/Y, Obj2 X/Y, alpha channel
            var rtn:Boolean = bmd1.hitTest(new Point(_obj1.x, _obj1.y), 255, bmd2, new Point(_obj2.x, _obj2.y), 255);

            // Dispose the bitmap data, we dont need it anymore
            if (!_debug) {
                bmd1.dispose();
                bmd2.dispose();
            }


            // Return the boolean
            return rtn;
        }

        /**
         * This ONLY needs to be called once a collision has been confirmed. Don't run this on every frame!
         * @return
         */
        private function getHitPoint(_obj1:Sprite, _obj2:Sprite, _debug:Boolean = false):Point {
            var rtnPoint:Point = new Point();

            // Draw the first item to bitmapdata
            var bmd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_obj1.width, _obj1.height, true, 0);
            // ..and the second
            var bmd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_obj2.width, _obj2.height, true, 0);

            // Now draw them
            bmd1.draw(_obj1);
            bmd2.draw(_obj2);

            // Create two bitmaps
            var bmp1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd1);
            var bmp2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd2);

            // Position
            bmp1.x = _obj1.x;
            bmp2.x = _obj2.x;
            bmp1.y = _obj1.y;
            bmp2.y = _obj2.y;

            // Get the origins
            var bitmapOrigin:Point = new Point(_obj1.x, _obj1.y);
            var bitmapTwoOriginLocal:Point = bmp2.globalToLocal(bitmapOrigin);

            // Find all the overlapping pixels
            var overlappingPixels:Vector.<uint> = bmp2.bitmapData.getVector(new Rectangle(bitmapTwoOriginLocal.x, bitmapTwoOriginLocal.y, _obj1.width, _obj1.height));

            var i:uint = 0;
            var len:uint = overlappingPixels.length;

            // Run through them all until we find a non-zero value
            for(i; i < len; i++) {
                if(overlappingPixels[i] != 0) {
                    // Our X collision is i % _obj1.width plus whichever X value is highest
                    rtnPoint.x = (i % _obj1.width) + (bmp2.x > bmp1.x ? bmp2.x : bmp1.x);
                    // Our Y collision is i / _obj1.height plus whichever Y value is highest
                    rtnPoint.y = (uint((i + 1) / _obj1.width)) + (bmp2.y > bmp1.y ? bmp2.y : bmp1.y);

                    // If debug, draw the collision point
                    if (_debug) {
                        var test:Sprite = new Sprite();
                        test.graphics.beginFill(0x008c6f);
                        test.graphics.drawRect(rtnPoint.x , rtnPoint.y, 10, 10);
                        test.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(test);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            // Send it back
            return rtnPoint;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow, and I'll accept your answer if it works

Comment: For some reason `checkCollision()` always returns false, even if the objects are added to the stage and you can see them colliding

Comment: Try passing true as the final parameter into checkCollision to see where the bitmap's are moving. Are you sure your center point is top left?

Comment: When I create a `Bitmap` out of the `BitmapData`s and add it to the stage, nothing changes

Comment: The function has a parameter for debug. private function checkCollision(_obj1:Sprite, _obj2:Sprite, _debug:Boolean = false):Boolean {}. Pass the 3rd variable as true.

Comment: still, the `bitmap`s aren't shown. And the center points of the objects which are tested can be anywhere

Comment: If the center points are not top left, the above will not work. The initial two points need to be the top left. If the bitmaps are not showing, that also means that the points being given are out, which will be related to the center point.

Comment: I guess I could then do `getBounds()` on the objects and use the resulting `x` and `y` value?

Comment: I edited my answer to the code I've got now (still doesn't work although I get the top-left `x` and `y` value)

Comment: It still doesn't draw anything to the stage?

Comment: Multiple things wrong with what you've shown. Hold on.

Comment: Okay so firstly, get rid of the static method. You can't access stage, or addChild within there. It should be throwing errors. Secondly, if you want to draw to the stage from the function, comment out the two dispose functions on the bitmapdata. Thirdly, assuming the previous, change the final 0 in the bitmapdata to be a colour (i use 0xff0000). Lastly, try using my exact function for checkCollision. I just copy/pasted it, threw on two movieclips and randomly moved their X/Y and it works. It will only fail to work if you apply rotations.

Comment: I've edited to include my comments in the code. Calling this with "checkCollision(obj1, obj2, true)" will now draw to screen.

Comment: I fixed it (don't ask me how because I don't know), and I know how I can get the top and bottom hit point (just do `overlappingPixels.reverse()` to get the bottom one) - but is there also a way to get the left and right hitpoint?

Comment: I fixed a small mistake in `getHitPoint()` (see the edit). Is there also a way to get the leftmost, rightmost, and bottom hitpoint? If you know a way, please answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825469/get-the-upper-bottom-rightmost-and-leftmost-point-of-a-pixel-perfect-bitmapdat)

Comment: You would do the same thing as I do for top, but for the height instead of width. :)

Comment: Could you please explain that? I'm afraid I don't really get it (BTW, I already found out how to get the bottom point, see the new question)

Comment: I'll reply to the other Q