# Get the upper, bottom, rightmost and leftmost point of a pixel-perfect BitmapData collision

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, 2d, collision-detection

How can I get  the upper, bottom, rightmost and leftmost point of a pixel-perfect BitmapData collision? This is my collision-detection code:

```
public static function checkCollision(object1:*, object2:*, debug:Boolean = false):Boolean{
    var object1Rect:Rectangle = object1.getRect(stage);
    var object2Rect:Rectangle = object2.getRect(stage);
    var object1Point:Point = new Point(object1Rect.x, object1Rect.y);
    var object2Point:Point = new Point(object2Rect.x, object2Rect.y);

    var bitmapData1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
        object1Rect.width, 
        object1Rect.height, 
        true, 
        0
    );
    var bitmapData2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
        object2Rect.width, 
        object2Rect.height, 
        true, 
        0
    );

    var clr:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
    if(debug)
        clr.color = 0x00ff00;

    bitmapData1.draw(object1, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -object1Rect.x, -object1Rect.y), clr);
    bitmapData2.draw(object2, null, clr);

    if(debug){
        if(bmp1.stage)
            stage.removeChild(bmp1);
        bmp1 = new Bitmap(bitmapData1);
        bmp1.x = object1Point.x;
        bmp1.y = object1Point.y;
        stage.addChild(bmp1);

        if(bmp2.stage)
            stage.removeChild(bmp2);
        bmp2 = new Bitmap(bitmapData2);
        bmp2.x = object2Point.x;
        bmp2.y = object2Point.y;
        stage.addChild(bmp2);
    }

    var bCollide:Boolean = bitmapData1.hitTest(
        object1Point,
        255,
        bitmapData2,
        object2Point,
        255
    );

    if(!debug){
        bitmapData1.dispose();
        bitmapData2.dispose();
    }
        return bCollide;
}
```

And it works perfeclty fine. However, the code I use to detect the top hitpoint doesn't work properly. This is the code:

```
public static function getHitPoint(object1:*, object2:*):Point{
    var point:Point = new Point();

    var object1Rect:Rectangle = object1.getRect(stage);
    var object2Rect:Rectangle = object2.getRect(stage);
    var object1Point:Point = new Point(object1Rect.x, object1Rect.y);
    var object2Point:Point = new Point(object2Rect.x, object2Rect.y);

    var bitmapData1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
        object1.width, 
        object1.height, 
        true, 
        0
    );
    var bitmapData2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
        object2.width, 
        object2.height, 
        true, 
        0
    );

    bitmapData1.draw(object1, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -object1Rect.x, -object1Rect.y));
    bitmapData2.draw(object2);

    var bitmap1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData1);
    var bitmap2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData2);

    bitmap1.x = object1Point.x;
    bitmap1.y = object1Point.y;
    bitmap2.x = object2Point.x;
    bitmap2.y = object2Point.y;

    var bitmapOrigin:Point = new Point(object1Point.x, object1Point.y);
    var bitmap2OriginLocal:Point = bitmap2.globalToLocal(bitmapOrigin);

    var overlappingPixels:Vector.<uint> = bitmap2.bitmapData.getVector(
        new Rectangle(bitmap2OriginLocal.x, bitmap2OriginLocal.y, object1Rect.width, object1Rect.height)
    );

    for(var i:String in overlappingPixels){
        var index:uint = uint(i);
        if(overlappingPixels[i] != 0){
            point.x = (index % object1.width) + (bitmap2.x > bitmap1.x ? bitmap2.x : bitmap1.x);
            point.y = (uint(index / bitmap1.height)) + (bitmap2.y > bitmap1.y ? bitmap2.y : bitmap1.y);
            break;
        }
    }

    return point;
}
```

I've got no idea why, but the `getHitPoint()` function sometimes returns the wrong coordinates. Can anyone please explain why that is? And how can I detect the bottommost, the leftmost and the rightmost hitpoint?

**Edit**
I now know why `getHitPoint()` sometimes returned a wrong value: `point.y = (uint(index / bitmap1.height)) + (bitmap2.y > bitmap1.y ? bitmap2.y : bitmap1.y);` should be `point.y = (uint(index/bitmap1.`**`width`**`)) + (bitmap2.y > bitmap1.y ? bitmap2.y : bitmap1.y);`

**Edit 2**
I found out how to get the bottom hitpoint:

```
public static function getHitPoint(object1:*, object2:*, direction:int = 0):*{
    var point:Point = new Point();

    var object1Rect:Rectangle = object1.getRect(stage);
    var object2Rect:Rectangle = object2.getRect(stage);
    var object1Point:Point = new Point(object1Rect.x, object1Rect.y);
    var object2Point:Point = new Point(object2Rect.x, object2Rect.y);

    var bitmapData1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
        Math.round(object1Rect.width), 
        Math.round(object1Rect.height), 
        true, 
        0
    );
    var bitmapData2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
        Math.round(object2Rect.width), 
        Math.round(object2Rect.height), 
        true, 
        0
    );

    bitmapData1.draw(object1, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -object1Rect.x, -object1Rect.y));
    bitmapData2.draw(object2);

    var bitmap1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData1);
    var bitmap2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData2);

    bitmap1.x = object1Point.x;
    bitmap1.y = object1Point.y;
    bitmap2.x = object2Point.x;
    bitmap2.y = object2Point.y;

    var bitmapOrigin:Point = new Point(object1Point.x, object1Point.y);
    var bitmap2OriginLocal:Point = bitmap2.globalToLocal(bitmapOrigin);

    var overlappingPixels:Vector.<uint> = bitmap2.bitmapData.getVector(
        new Rectangle(bitmap2OriginLocal.x, bitmap2OriginLocal.y, object1Rect.width, object1Rect.height)
    );

    switch(direction){
        case 0: //top
            for(var i:String in overlappingPixels){
                var index:uint = uint(i);
                if(overlappingPixels[i] != 0){
                    point.x = (index % bitmap1.width) + (bitmap2.x > bitmap1.x ? bitmap2.x : bitmap1.x);
                    point.y = (uint((index)/bitmap1.width)) + (bitmap2.y > bitmap1.y ? bitmap2.y : bitmap1.y);
                    return point;
                }
            }

        case 1: //right
            // I still need this

        case 2: //bottom
            overlappingPixels.reverse();

            for(var i:String in overlappingPixels){
                var index:uint = uint(i);
                if(overlappingPixels[i] != 0){
                    point.x = bitmap1.width - (index % bitmap1.width) + (bitmap2.x > bitmap1.x ? bitmap2.x : bitmap1.x);
                    point.y =  (bitmap2.y + bitmap2.height > bitmap1.y + bitmap1.height ? bitmap1.y + bitmap1.height : bitmap2.y + bitmap2.height) - (uint(index/bitmap1.width));
                    return point;
                }
            }

        case 3: //left
            // I still need this too
    }
    return false;
}
```

I still need a way to get the left and rightmost hitpoints though

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the globalToLocal call seems a bit out of place as you don't add the bitmaps to a display object container. You can try tracing bitmapOrigin and bitmap2Original to see if their values are what you intend to get.

Comment: @CristinaGeorgescu I traced them, and they are right. BTW, the seems that only moment when `getHitPoint()` is a little off is when `bitmap2.y` is bigger than `bitmap1.y`, although I can't see why

Comment: The above is also sorted in the code that I've provided below. I had made a mistake in my original code on the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it like you're doing there. You can do it all within a single function, which returns everything back correctly. I've added comments to the below. Please take note of what I've changed, as when you're trying to do it as you're doing now, with the code you changed, it is impossible.

This works for any shape, any direction. It'll give you the exact X and Y of the collision.

Please *do not* make this into a static function. Put it into a global class and use a Singleton to manage it instead. Things start to go very badly wrong when you being using static functions and reference the stage.

Also, if you're going to be working with pixel values of less than 1 (ie 99.75), the below will need a bit of adapting to cater for that. I've assumed you're using whole pixels, given your Math.round usage.

```
     /**
     * 
     * @param   object1
     * @param   object2
     * @return
     */
    private function getHitPoint(object1:*, object2:*):*{
        var point:Point;

        // X and Y where we hit
        // do NOT change this to a stage location or it does NOT work
        var object1Point:Point = new Point(object1.x, object1.y);
        var object2Point:Point = new Point(object2.x, object2.y);

        var bitmapData1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
            Math.round(object1.width), 
            Math.round(object1.height), 
            true, 
            0
        );
        var bitmapData2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
            Math.round(object2.width), 
            Math.round(object2.height), 
            true, 
            0
        );

        // Draw
        bitmapData1.draw(object1, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -object1.x, -object1.y));
        bitmapData2.draw(object2);

        // Create BMP's
        var bitmap1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData1);
        var bitmap2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData2);

        // Set X and Y and BMP
        bitmap1.x = object1Point.x;
        bitmap1.y = object1Point.y;
        bitmap2.x = object2Point.x;
        bitmap2.y = object2Point.y;

        // BMP origin is the object1 X and Y
        var bitmapOrigin:Point = new Point(object1Point.x, object1Point.y);
        // Create a local version of the bitmap2 so we can see what is overlapping
        var bitmap2OriginLocal:Point = bitmap2.globalToLocal(bitmapOrigin);

        // Create a rectangle from what we now know
        var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(bitmap2OriginLocal.x, bitmap2OriginLocal.y, object1.width, object1.height);

        // The overlapping pixels are within the rectangle, so get them all
        var overlappingPixels:Vector.<uint> = bitmap2.bitmapData.getVector(rect);

        // Run through all the overlapping pixels until we find a colourful one
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < overlappingPixels.length; i++ ) {
            var index:uint = overlappingPixels[i];

            // If the colour is not 0, we have found it
            if(index != 0){
                point = new Point();

                // Basically, instead of using width and getting 100, we're working out how
                // many pixles across the overlap is. The Vector doesn't tell us this, so we need to work it out
                var overlappingWidth:uint = object1.width - Math.abs(bitmap2OriginLocal.x);

                // The Y is object1.y, minus the local y, plus object1's width minus the X from the local
                point.y = object1.y - bitmap2OriginLocal.y + uint(i / overlappingWidth);
                // The X is the same as above, but % of the width
                point.x = object1.x - bitmap2OriginLocal.x + (i % overlappingWidth);

                // Found it, we're done
                break;
            }

        }

        // Only fires when you've got a collision that is less than 1 pixel from the width or height
        // Just a fail safe
        if (!point) {
            point = new Point(object1.width, object1.height);
        }

        return point;
    }
```

For context, my entire class is below which shows how I was using this function. You can copy/paste this class and it will work. It shows how you move sprites around the screen, once it finds a collision, then it works out where the collision took place.

This class is for absolute pixel perfect collision detection, including an example.

```
package kazo 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author KM
     */
    public class TestCases2 extends Sprite
    {

        private var rect    :Sprite;
        private var circle  :Sprite;

        /**
         * 
         */
        public function TestCases2() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        public function init(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            trace('Starting test case');

            // Rectangle
            rect = new Sprite();
            // Circle
            circle = new Sprite();

            // Draw the rectangle. Center point must be TOP LEFT
            // If you're using Flash Professional, place everything at 0,0 inside the MC
            rect.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
            rect.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
            rect.graphics.endFill();

            // Draw the circle. Center point is TOP LEFT, so the X and Y of the circle need to be equal to the radius
            circle.graphics.beginFill(0xffff00);
            circle.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 50);
            circle.graphics.endFill();

            // Add them
            addChild(rect);
            addChild(circle);

            // Position
            rect.x = 225;
            rect.y = 75;

            // Position
            circle.x = 225;
            circle.y = 225;

            // Frame loop
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameFunc);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function frameFunc(e:Event):void {
            // move them around
            circle.y -= 2;
            circle.x += 0;
            rect.y += 1;
            rect.x += 0;

            // Check for collisions. If found, stop. Pass 'true' as the final param if you want it to draw to the screen
            if (checkCollision(rect, circle)) {
                var ref:Point = getHitPoint(rect, circle);

                // Draws where the collision hit
                var loc:Sprite = new Sprite();
                loc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
                loc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
                loc.graphics.endFill();
                addChild(loc);

                loc.x = ref.x;
                loc.y = ref.y;

                trace(ref);

                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameFunc);
            }
        }

         /**
         * 
         * @param   _obj1
         * @param   _obj2
         * @param   _debug
         * @return
         */
        private function checkCollision(_obj1:Sprite, _obj2:Sprite, _debug:Boolean = false):Boolean {
            // Draw the first item to bitmapdata
            var bmd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_obj1.width, _obj1.height, true, 0);
            // ..and the second
            var bmd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_obj2.width, _obj2.height, true, 0);

            // Now draw them
            bmd1.draw(_obj1);
            bmd2.draw(_obj2);

            // If we're in debug, also add the bitmap to the stage so we can see where we are
            if (_debug) {
                var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd1);
                bmp.x = _obj1.x;
                bmp.y = _obj1.y;
                addChild(bmp);

                var bmp2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd2);
                bmp2.x = _obj2.x;
                bmp2.y = _obj2.y;
                addChild(bmp2);
            }

            // Hit test including alpha channel. Obj1 X/Y, Obj2 X/Y, alpha channel
            var rtn:Boolean = bmd1.hitTest(new Point(_obj1.x, _obj1.y), 255, bmd2, new Point(_obj2.x, _obj2.y), 255);

            // Dispose the bitmap data, we dont need it anymore
            if (!_debug) {
                bmd1.dispose();
                bmd2.dispose();
            }


            // Return the boolean
            return rtn;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   object1
         * @param   object2
         * @return
         */
        private function getHitPoint(object1:*, object2:*):*{
            var point:Point;

            // X and Y where we hit
            // do NOT change this to a stage location or it does NOT work
            var object1Point:Point = new Point(object1.x, object1.y);
            var object2Point:Point = new Point(object2.x, object2.y);

            var bitmapData1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
                Math.round(object1.width), 
                Math.round(object1.height), 
                true, 
                0
            );
            var bitmapData2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
                Math.round(object2.width), 
                Math.round(object2.height), 
                true, 
                0
            );

            // Draw
            bitmapData1.draw(object1, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -object1.x, -object1.y));
            bitmapData2.draw(object2);

            // Create BMP's
            var bitmap1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData1);
            var bitmap2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData2);

            // Set X and Y and BMP
            bitmap1.x = object1Point.x;
            bitmap1.y = object1Point.y;
            bitmap2.x = object2Point.x;
            bitmap2.y = object2Point.y;

            // BMP origin is the object1 X and Y
            var bitmapOrigin:Point = new Point(object1Point.x, object1Point.y);
            // Create a local version of the bitmap2 so we can see what is overlapping
            var bitmap2OriginLocal:Point = bitmap2.globalToLocal(bitmapOrigin);

            // Create a rectangle from what we now know
            var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(bitmap2OriginLocal.x, bitmap2OriginLocal.y, object1.width, object1.height);

            // The overlapping pixels are within the rectangle, so get them all
            var overlappingPixels:Vector.<uint> = bitmap2.bitmapData.getVector(rect);

            // Run through all the overlapping pixels until we find a colourful one
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < overlappingPixels.length; i++ ) {
                var index:uint = overlappingPixels[i];

                // If the colour is not 0, we have found it
                if(index != 0){
                    point = new Point();

                    // Basically, instead of using width and getting 100, we're working out how
                    // many pixles across the overlap is. The Vector doesn't tell us this, so we need to work it out
                    var overlappingWidth:uint = object1.width - Math.abs(bitmap2OriginLocal.x);

                    // The Y is object1.y, minus the local y, plus object1's width minus the X from the local
                    point.y = object1.y - bitmap2OriginLocal.y + uint(i / overlappingWidth);
                    // The X is the same as above, but % of the width
                    point.x = object1.x - bitmap2OriginLocal.x + (i % overlappingWidth);

                    // Found it, we're done
                    break;
                }

            }

            // Only fires when you've got a collision that is less than 1 pixel from the width or height
            // Just a fail safe
            if (!point) {
                point = new Point(object1.width, object1.height);
            }

            return point;
        }

    }

}
```